# Webpack throws Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In my react component the web pack throws the following error and I am not sure what is wrong. The webpack.config file is also added
`
    import React, {Component} from 'react'
    import './Banner.css'

```
class Banner extends Component {
    constructor(props){

        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <p>
                 What are you doing
            </p>
        );
    }
}
export default Banner;`
```

**The error is as follows:**
`ERROR in ./src/components/Banner.js
Module parse failed: /Users/allenord/Documents/Developer/PersonalPage/src/components/Banner.js Unexpected token (13:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   render(){
|     return(
|         <p>
|           What are you doing
|         </p>
 @ ./src/app/index.jsx 11:14-48
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./src/app/index.jsx`

**webpack.config**

```
var config = {
   entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
   output: {
   path: BUILD_DIR,
   filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module : {
loaders : [
  {
    test : /\.jsx?/,
    include : APP_DIR,
    loader : 'babel-loader'
  },
  {
    include:'/src',
    test    : /\.scss$/,
    loaders : [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader?sourceMap&-minimize',
      'postcss',
      'sass?sourceMap'
    ]
  },
  {
    include:'/src',
    test    : /\.css$/,
    loaders : [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader?sourceMap&-minimize'
    ]
  }
]
},
```

Comment: what is on line 13 at position 8 in your code?

Comment: It is the <p> tag

Comment: how your .babelrc looks like?

Comment: `{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react"]
}
`

Comment: Do I have to add the extensions in babelrc file?

Comment: What do you have in the APP_DIR variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a Webpack loader to be able to import anything that is not JS. In your case, you need a CSS loader to make the line `import './Banner.css'` works.

More info: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#styling

Comment: I actually have a loader in my webpack.config. I updated the post to include the config file.

Comment: As the error is at the `<p>` tag, looks like your file is not going through the Babel loader, which should understand the JSX content (with the react preset).
Check your include setting. Looks like APP_DIR is `./src/app` but your componente is inside `./src/components`.

Comment: I can't believe that